# About the template for poll recent block in drupal 7

Tags: theming

I need a template for the poll recent block in drupal 7.  I have tried with block--poll.tpl.php and block--poll--recent.tpl.php and poll--recent--block.tpl.php and I can't see any changes.  What's my wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`block--poll--recent.tpl.php` will work if you clear your system cache (configuration > development > performance > clear all caches).

Worked for me.

See complete template suggestion list for Drupal 7 here : http://drupal.org/node/1089656

Comment: It's correct... I forgot to clean cache and I couldn't see the changes.  Many thanks.